# Handling Timeout Error(python)

Tags: python

```
import multiprocessing.pool
import functools
import time
import sys
def timeout(max_timeout):
    def timeout_decorator(item):
        @functools.wraps(item)
        def func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            pool = multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool(processes=1)
            async_result = pool.apply_async(item, args, kwargs)
            return async_result.get(max_timeout)
        return func_wrapper
    return timeout_decorator
```

I got this code from SE. This raises the timeout error from system level.
How could i handle this error and do something else when error pops up

Please Note Am a newbie in python.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap an error, using a try/except :

```
try:
    do_something_that_can_raise_error_X()
except X:
    do_something_when_error_X_is_raised()
```

Comment: I already used that still it could not capture that Timeout Error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the code that might raise this exception in "try" and then except the exception that you expect.

```
from multiprocessing import TimeoutError

try:
    # actions that raise TimeoutError
except TimeoutError:
    # handle TimeoutError
else:
    # (optional) actions for when there is no TimeoutError
finally:
    # (optional) actions to perform in any case
```

See this [example in the multiprocessing docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers).

Note, that using except without listing precise exception types is allowed syntactically but is not a good idea.

Also, you might want to learn how to handle Exceptions in python, see any python tutorial.

Comment: @timeout(10)
def sleep1():
    try:
        time.sleep(20)
    except TimeoutError:
        print "Timeout occurs" Still i got Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\test1.py", line 24, in <module>
    sleep1()
  File "D:\test1.py", line 12, in func_wrapper
    return async_result.get(max_timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 550, in get
    raise TimeoutError
TimeoutError

Comment: time.sleep(20) is not the code that raises TimeoutError. You must put inside try/except the part of your code that actually uses multiprocessing. Look again at how they make a single worker sleep for 10 secs and except the TimeoutError in that example from the docs.